# How to rsync that excludes .git/ folder but still keep the .git/config file?

Tags: linux, git, rsync

**In brief TLDR**

To rsync a folder that has .git/ excluded but still keeping the .git/config file, how to do that?

My [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+rsync+a+folder+except+.git+folder+but+keep+.git%2Fconfig+file&oq=how+to+rsync+a+folder+except+.git+folder+but+keep+.git%2Fconfig+file&aqs=chrome..69i57.12682j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is not helpful so I asked here.

**Full details**

I want to take snapshot of all of my projects' code into another machine - later on I may not have the git repo access.

Each project code folder is a git-cloned one so they have .git folder.

I don't need those .git so will exclude them.

But I need to know what git repo the projects coming from so need to keep .git/config.

What I tried and didn't work [run it](https://repl.it/@NamG1/rsync-exlude-git-include-gitconfig-NOT-WORKING)

```
rsync -chazvP --dry-run --exclude=".git" --include=".git/config"  $FROM/ $TO/
#             .         .                .                        .      .
```

If you know the correct way to do so, please share.

Comment: That sounds like a task for... well, for git. I think we're dealing with an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What problem are you trying to solve with rsync here?

Comment: The problem is "rsync a folder that has .git/ excluded but still keeping the .git/config file" a.k.a. when we do `exclude .git/` the whole folder excluded and now we want to `keep .git/config`, how to? @gronostaj

Comment: Have you read the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) link I've posted above? You've described Y. Running rsync is not your ultimate goal, it's your solution for problem X. What's the X that you want to solve?

Comment: Yes I read though not get the X there; got it now after you explained @gronostaj, thank you! My X is "take snapshot of all of my projects' code into another machine"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the file you want to keep, and then exclude the ones you don't want. You can't exclude the `.git/` directory itself, though, because then there would be no match for `.git/config`.

```
rsync --dry-run -av --include '.git/config' --exclude '.git/*' "$FROM/" "$TO/"
```

As always, test it first and then remove `--dry-run` when you're comfortable. Remember to double-quote your variables, to protect them from the shell's word expansions.

For reference, this is described in the documentation (`man rsync`), but I'll be one of the first to say it's hard to understand unless you already understand it...

> For instance, to include "/foo/bar/baz", the directories "/foo" and
> "/foo/bar" must not be excluded. Excluding one of those parent
> directories prevents the examination of its content, cutting off
> rsync’s recursion into those paths and rendering the include for
> "/foo/bar/baz" ineffectual (since rsync can’t match something it never
> sees in the cut-off section of the directory hierarchy).
>
> The concept path exclusion is particularly important when using a
> trailing ’*’ rule. For instance, this won’t work:
>
> ```
> + /some/path/this-file-will-not-be-found
> + /file-is-included
> - *
> ```
>
> This fails because the parent directory "some" is excluded by the ’*’
> rule, so rsync never visits any of the files in the "some" or
> "some/path" directories. [...] **Another solution is to add specific
> include rules for all the parent dirs that need to be visited.**

Comment: Great thanks @roaima for your detailed and very-careful answer! I'll try and back to you soon with trying `--include '.git/config' --exclude '.git/*' ` .

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you @roaima!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment:

> My X is "take snapshot of all of my projects' code into another machine"

I'd suggest just using git. It internally tracks code as directory snapshots, so you get everything rsync does + git goodies.

Git can access other repos over SSH, HTTP and even from mounted filesystems. Since rsync was your tool of choice, I assume you already have SSH set up. In case you need to update something in particular for git to work, [here's a guide](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server).

Once you have your repo cloned on 2nd machine, `git fetch --all` will efficiently update local clone of your repo only with files that were updated since last fetch.

Alternatively you can `git init --bare` a new repo on 2nd machine and add it as a remote on the 1st one. In that case you can execute `git push --all` on machine 1 to update machine 2.

Or you can make both repos remotes of each other, so you're able to initiate the update on both ends.

Why git is the perfect solution?

- You're already working with git, so you don't have to introduce another tool you're not familiar with
- Avoids reinventing the wheel
- You don't have to parse `.git/config` in your head, `git remote get-url origin` will tell you repo's origin
- Git compresses and deduplicates your files
- Branches and commit history are preserved
- Only changes are transferred, rather than entire snapshot

Comment: Thanks for your solution with git-base. My scenario is that some git repo after migrated, I may stop having the access later on.

Comment: Added "later on I may not have the git repo access" to my question to clarify. Thanks any wat.

Comment: @NamGVU My solution is still valid. Git repos are completely independent from each other. Even if you lose access to the origin, clones will remain untouched.